# How to add a font size button to my website HTML, JavaScript, & CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a button that controls the font size of my website.
When I press the font button, I want all my fonts to increase in size.

I've tried using  JavaScript, HTML, & CSS.

The problem I'm facing is that some of the text on my website isn't increasing in size when I press the button.

[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVNyq.png)

My Code below

```
<!--HTML -->
<button onclick="fontsize()">FontSize</button>
  
/*CSS:*/
    body.fontsize {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
      font-size: 3rem;
  }

// JavaScript: //

function fontsize() {
  // Toggling the class "fontsize" on the body
  document.body.classList.toggle("fontsize");
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the parts about providing a [mcve] and avoiding depending on links to allow people to understand your problem.

Comment: The code you provided appears to work fine, so the issue must be somewhere in the code you haven't provided, or there's something different about your actual code. https://jsfiddle.net/wfruj7kz/

Comment: You want the font-size to increase on every click or to a maximum?

Comment: your code only works if there's no other element with `font-size` specified. take @SeanSutherland's snippet, if I add another element and set its font-size in pixels via css, clicking the button won't affect it: https://jsfiddle.net/0tj7geav/ are all your elements sized in rem?

Comment: Every time I click font size I want my fonts to increase in size, and when I click the button again I want the font sizes to return to the normal size again.

Comment: @GrafiCode
Oh, okay, thank  you
I understand
I see my problem now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you provided works on its own, so the issue you're seeing in the provided video is most likely that you have font-sizes set further down in the DOM that are overriding the font-size of `body`.

Your edits clarified that you're specifically looking for a font-size toggle button. You can do this with a simple class toggle if you apply it to the root element (`<html>`) and **use "rem" units to specify all of the font sizes** in your html. **This also preserves the relative sizes of text when it gets bigger or smaller.**

(It has to be `html` element, not `body` because `rem` scale base on the "root" element of the document)

Run the below snippet for a demo.

```js
function fontsize_1() {
  // Toggling the class "fontsize" on the body
  document.body.classList.toggle("fontsize");
}

function fontsize_2() {
  // Toggling the class "fontsize" on the html
  document.querySelector("html").classList.toggle("fontsize");
}
```

```css
body.fontsize {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  font-size: 200%;
}

html.fontsize {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  font-size: 200%;
}

/* example sizes */
.px {
  font-size: 12px
}

.rem {
  font-size: 1rem
}

.rem-small {
  font-size: .6rem
}

.rem-big {
  font-size: 1.5rem
}

/* color the border of the active button */
body.fontsize #b1, html.fontsize #b2 {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML -->
<button onclick="fontsize_1()" id="b1">FontSize, body</button>
<button onclick="fontsize_2()" id="b2">FontSize, html</button>
<table width=100%><tr>
  <td>
    <p>No font size</p>
    <p class="px">Font size in px</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="rem-big">Big font size in rem</div>
    <div class="rem">Font size in rem</div>
    <div class="rem-small">Small font size in rem</div>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

(I had to use `document.querySelector("html")` instead of `document.html` because otherwise it wouldn't work inside a stackoverflow snippet)

Comment: The problem with this, and it's just unrealistic in the real world... if you're going to increase the font size (likely for accessibility issues), you'll need to be able to bring the font size back down. My solution above does this.

Comment: Ideally, the limiting options you've provided don't give the user to ability to choose the font-size that's right for them... which just creates another accessibility issue.

Comment: @Millhorn My goal was to answer the question OP actually asked, not interrogate them over an XY problem. OP asked for a single toggle for big font (if you check the code, you'll note toggling it *does* bring the font size back down). More importantly, your answer also doesn't explain or solve OP's actual problem, which is that he likely has font sizes set manually further down in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided, I'm guessing it's a style inheritance issue. The text that doesn't change size, likely has text styling from a closer ancestor. This will overwrite any styling changes you make to the body. If you inspect one of the text elements that won't upsize, you can see the styling inheritance in the Styles section of the Inspector. Any ancestor styling that has been replaced by styling done to a closer ancestor will be crossed out.

I suggest you solve this issue by setting all your font sizes in rem, and programmatically changing the font size in the `<html>` element style attribute (which determines how many pixels is in a rem). In the example below, I use the Element methods `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` to conditionally change that.  [(setAttribute syntax)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)
[(removeAttribute syntax)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

```js
const htmlEl = document.querySelector("html")

const largeFontSize = 30 //how many px per rem you want for your big font size

let isLarge = false

function toggleFontSize() {
isLarge ? htmlEl.removeAttribute("style") : htmlEl.setAttribute("style", `font-size: ${largeFontSize}px `)
  
  isLarge = !isLarge
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-container {
  font-size: .8rem;
}

button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button onClick="toggleFontSize()">Toggle font-size</button>

  <h1>child</h1>

  <div class="text-container">
    <h1>nested descendant</h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

This will update all font sizes assigned using rem and will maintain proportions as well.

Comment: Realistically, this wouldn't work well because you're also lowering the font-sizes of the + and - signs in the buttons. Eventually, they would appear to disappear from the page.

Comment: @Millhorn Accessibility-wise, the text inside buttons need to change too. The issue you are referring to could be easily avoided by adding a conditional operator to the decreaseFontSize function. I just wanted to show that the text will scale proportionally. But I should have provided a toggle button, as OP suggested. My bad.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

In order to increase the font-size, you'll need to wrap everything in a container of some kind. In this case, I wrapped all your code in a `main` selector and then called it in JS, and applied the function to that selector.

```js
const increment = document.getElementById("up"),
  decrement = document.getElementById("down"),
  fsize = document.querySelector("main"),
  step = 2;

fsize.style.fontSize = "30px";

increment.onclick = function() {
  fsize.style.fontSize = parseInt(fsize.style.fontSize) + step + "px";
};

decrement.onclick = function() {
  fsize.style.fontSize = parseInt(fsize.style.fontSize) - step + "px";
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

main h2,
main h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.font {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .font {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .font {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .font {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="font">
    <p>Change Font Size: </p>
    <button id="down">-</button>
    <button id="up">+</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <main>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <h4>I am a subtitle</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, temporibus aut! Distinctio rem, mollitia vero necessitatibus aliquid aliquam eveniet modi reiciendis quo ad illo. Ipsum quo obcaecati quidem commodi reprehenderit!</p>
    <p>Impedit rerum natus aliquam at sequi harum. Quas modi exercitationem deleniti officia commodi vitae impedit consectetur non, porro reprehenderit expedita fugiat! Nostrum aliquam laboriosam fuga architecto dignissimos impedit id iusto.</p>
    <p>Ipsa, molestiae voluptates! Assumenda placeat velit totam, rerum recusandae nobis nisi doloribus quam error labore molestias officia eos laudantium quia enim, impedit, ea tenetur beatae et nemo nostrum? Recusandae, odio.</p>
  </main>
</div>
```